# When clicking on hamburger menu it opens up menu but I can see the homepage text on top of the menu

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am building responsive portfolio page with ReactJS and Tailwind CSS. When the screen is below the medim breakpoint, the hamburger menu icon appears. When I click on the hamburger icon I can see the menu items, but my home page text appears to be on the top of the menu items. Any ideas how to fix this?

[Screenshot of opened hamburger menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2eG5.png)

**NavBar component:**

```
const NavBar = () => {
  const [hamburgerMenu, setHamburgerMenu] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => setHamburgerMenu(!hamburgerMenu);

  return (
    <div className="bg-gradient-to-r from-rose-500 via-red-400 to-red-500 fixed w-full h-[80px] flex justify-between items-center px-4 text-white shadow-xl">
        <div>
            <img src={Logo} alt='Logo' style={{width: '110px'}}></img>
        </div>

        {/*menu: anything below medium it will hide*/}
          <ul className='hidden md:flex'>
            <li className='hover:scale-110 duration-300'>Home</li>
            <li className='hover:scale-110 duration-300'>About Me</li>
            <li className='hover:scale-110 duration-300'>Skills</li>
            <li className='hover:scale-110 duration-300'>Projects</li>
            <li className='hover:scale-110 duration-300'>Contact Me</li>
          </ul>

        {/*hamburger: anything over medium (768px) it will hide*/}
        <div onClick={handleClick} className='md:hidden z-10 hover:text-red-700 cursor-pointer drop-shadow-lg hover:scale-110 duration-300'>
            { hamburgerMenu ? <FaTimes size={38} /> : <FaBars size={38}/> }
        </div>

        {/*Mobile menu*/}
          <ul className={hamburgerMenu ? "absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-screen bg-gradient-to-r from-rose-500 via-red-400 to-red-500 flex flex-col justify-center items-center" : "hidden"}>
            <li className='py-6 text-4xl hover:scale-110 duration-300'>Home</li>
            <li className='py-6 text-4xl hover:scale-110 duration-300'>About Me</li>
            <li className='py-6 text-4xl hover:scale-110 duration-300'>Skills</li>
            <li className='py-6 text-4xl hover:scale-110 duration-300'>Projects</li>
            <li className='py-6 text-4xl hover:scale-110 duration-300'>Contact Me</li>
          </ul>

        {/*Social media icons*/}
        <div className='hidden md:flex fixed flex-col top-[35%] left-0 text-red-500 drop-shadow-lg'>
            <ul>
              <li className='w-[195px] h-[60px] flex justify-between items-center ml-[-130px] hover:ml-[-10px] duration-300'>
                <a className='flex justify-between items-center w-full' href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/sigita-zebrauskaite-0258ab15b/" target='_blank'rel="noreferrer">Linkedin<BsLinkedin size={40}/></a>
              </li>
              <li className='w-[195px] h-[60px] flex justify-between items-center ml-[-130px] hover:ml-[-10px] duration-300'>
                <a className='flex justify-between items-center w-full' href="https://github.com/sigii1992" target='_blank' rel="noreferrer">GitHub<BsGithub size={40}/></a>
              </li>
              <li className='w-[195px] h-[60px] flex justify-between items-center ml-[-130px] hover:ml-[-10px] duration-300'>
                <a className='flex justify-between items-center w-full' href="mailto: sigita.zeb92@gmail.com" target='_blank' rel="noreferrer">Email<MdEmail size={40}/></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default NavBar;
```

**Home page component**:

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div name='home' className="w-full h-screen bg-gradient-to-r from-rose-100 to-teal-100 font-[Kanit]">

    {/*Container */}
        <div className="max-w-[1000px] mx-auto px-12 flex flex-col justify-center h-full">
          <p className="text-red-500 drop-shadow-lg">Hi, my name is</p>
          <h1 className="text-[#BC8F8F] text-4xl md:text-6xl font-bold drop-shadow-lg">...</h1>
          <h2 className="text-[#d18282] text-4xl md:text-6xl font-bold drop-shadow-lg">... </h2>
          <p className="text-[#BC8F8F] py-6 max-w-[1000px] drop-shadow-lg">.........................</p>
          <div>
              <button className='group text-white border-2 bg-red-500 rounded-full px-6 py-2 flex items-center hover:bg-red-700 hover:scale-110 duration-300'>View Work 
              <span className='group-hover:rotate-90 duration-300'>
              <BsArrowRight className='ml-2'/></span>
              </button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import Home from "./components/Home";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar />
      <Home />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Can you add the code where you are including the `NavBar` component on your page?

Comment: Hello @Ed Lucas I added the code snippet at the bottom of my post :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you've tried including a z-index, but it should be added to your absolutely positioned menu `ul`:

```
<ul className={hamburgerMenu ? "z-10 absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-screen bg-gradient-to-r from-rose-500 via-red-400 to-red-500 flex flex-col justify-center items-center" : "hidden"}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the css z-index of the overlay menu.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work

Comment: @sigiii what is the z-index of the text, and the z-index of the menu? it's pretty much certain to be related to this.

Comment: well the menu z-index is 10 and the text doesn't have one. I tried changing it but it doesn't  work ..

Comment: @sigiii okay, try adding `position: relative;` as well

Comment: I tried changing it but it didn't fix the problem...